# accessing the second time the fragment, the application crashes

Tags: android, android-fragments

everything works perfectly, but if you go a second time fragment2 button, the application stops. As I understand the log, this fragment is already open, or in this fragment has already opened another fragment.
Already it is beyond me please help

Main2activity:

```
case R.id.inbox:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Inbox Selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    ContentFragment fragment = new ContentFragment();
                    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

                    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                    fragmentTransaction.remove(fragment);
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame,fragment);
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();

                    return true;

                // For rest of the options we just show a toast on click

                case R.id.starred:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Stared Selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    ListVideoViewFragment fragment2 = new ListVideoViewFragment();
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction2 = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction2.addToBackStack(null);
                    fragmentTransaction2.remove(fragment2);
                    fragmentTransaction2.replace(R.id.frame,fragment2);
                    fragmentTransaction2.commit();

                    return true;

                case R.id.sent_mail:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Send Selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    return true;
```

Listviewfragment:

```
public class ListVideoViewFragment extends Fragment implements VideosFragment.Contract {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_list_video_view_fragment,container,false);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onVideoSelected(final String uri, String mimeType) {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle("Select");
        // builder.setMessage("Lorem ipsum dolor ....");
        builder.setItems(new CharSequence[]
                        {getString(R.string.play_video), getString(R.string.remove_video)},
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // The 'which' argument contains the index position
                        // of the selected item
                        switch (which) {
                            case 0:
                                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
                                intent.putExtra("url", uri);
                                startActivity(intent);
                                break;
                            case 1:

                                File file = new File(uri);

                                file.delete();

                                getActivity().sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.fromFile(new File(uri))));
                                //sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.fromFile(new File(uri))));
                                //   Main2Activity.this.getContentResolver().delete(Uri.fromFile(new File(uri)), null,null);

                                break;
                        }
                    }
                });
        builder.create().show();
    }
}
```

and videofragment :

```
public class VideosFragment extends ContractListFragment<VideosFragment.Contract> implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>, SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder {
    private ImageLoader imageLoader;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity host) {
        super.onAttach(host);

        ImageLoaderConfiguration ilConfig=
                new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(getActivity()).build();

        imageLoader=ImageLoader.getInstance();
        imageLoader.init(ilConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle state) {
        super.onActivityCreated(state);

        String[] from=
                { MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE, MediaStore.Video.Media._ID };
        int[] to= { android.R.id.text1, R.id.thumbnail };
        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter=
                new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.row, null,
                        from, to, 0);

        adapter.setViewBinder(this);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        CursorAdapter adapter=(CursorAdapter)getListAdapter();
        Cursor c=(Cursor)adapter.getItem(position);
        int uriColumn=c.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA);
        int mimeTypeColumn=
                c.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media.MIME_TYPE);

        getContract().onVideoSelected(c.getString(uriColumn),
                c.getString(mimeTypeColumn));
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int arg0, Bundle arg1) {
        return(new CursorLoader(
                getActivity(),
                MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                null, null, null,
                MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE));
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor c) {
        ((CursorAdapter)getListAdapter()).swapCursor(c);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        ((CursorAdapter)getListAdapter()).swapCursor(null);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean setViewValue(View v, Cursor c, int column) {
        if (column == c.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media._ID)) {
            Uri video=
                    ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                            c.getInt(column));
            DisplayImageOptions opts=new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                    .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.ic_media_video_poster)
                    .build();

            imageLoader.displayImage(video.toString(), (ImageView)v, opts);

            return(true);
        }

        return(false);
    }

    interface Contract {
        void onVideoSelected(String uri, String mimeType);
    }
}
```

and log:

```
                                                                         ---

------ beginning of crash
02-17 09:29:27.230 14035-14035/ro.vrt.videoplayerstreaming E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                             Process: ro.vrt.videoplayerstreaming, PID: 14035
                                                                             android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
                                                                                 at ro.vrt.videoplayerstreaming.ListVideoViewFragment.onCreateView(ListVideoViewFragment.java:21)
                                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962)
                                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
                                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1248)
                                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
                                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1613)
                                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                              Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:782)
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:941)
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:831)
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                                                 at ro.vrt.videoplayerstreaming.ListVideoViewFragment.onCreateView(ListVideoViewFragment.java:21) 
                                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962) 
                                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067) 
                                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1248) 
                                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738) 
                                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1613) 
                                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                                              Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #2: Duplicate id 0x7f120124, tag null, or parent id 0xffffffff with another fragment for ro.vrt.videoplayerstreaming.VideosFragment
                                                                                 at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2205)
                                                                                 at android.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:98)
                                                                                 at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:5546)
                                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:34)
                                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:79)
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:754)
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:941) 
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:831) 
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                                                 at ro.vrt.videoplayerstreaming.ListVideoViewFragment.onCreateView(ListVideoViewFragment.java:21) 
                                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962) 
                                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067) 
                                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1248) 
                                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738) 
                                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1613) 
                                                                                 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
02-17 09:29:29.559 14035-14035/ro.vrt.videoplayerstreaming I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 14035 SIG: 9
```

activity_list_video_view_fragment.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        layout="@layout/main"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/bShare"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/videos"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:name="ro.vrt.videoplayerstreaming.VideosFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/row" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am changed listvideoviewfragment , and nou is work

```
   public class ListVideoViewFragment extends Fragment {
    private static View view;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (view != null) {
            ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
            if (parent != null)
                parent.removeView(view);
        }
        try {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_list_video_view_fragment, container, false);
        } catch (InflateException e) {
        /* map is already there, just return view as it is */
        }
        return view;
    }
}
```